# Canonical product in sheaf cohomology

Tags: homological-algebra, cohomology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

**EDIT:** Let $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$ be sheaves of abelian groups on a topological space $X$. Then there exists a canonical cup product
$$H^i(X,\mathcal{F})\otimes_\mathbb{Z}H^j(X,\mathcal{G})\to H^{i+j}(\mathcal{F}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathcal{G}).$$
See e.g. Godement's book "Algebraic topology and sheaves theory", Ch. II, Section 6.6.

In Godement's book this map is constructed using a very special resolution of the sheaves, so called canonical resolution. In the answer by
user1128917 such a map can also be constructed for the Chech cohomology.

**(1) Is there a construction of the cup product using more general (say injective) resolutions rather than a particular canonical one? (2) Do the above two constructions give the same product provided the Chech cohomology is isomorphic to the sheaf cohomology?**

I guess the answer to the second question should be positive, but I do not have a (reference to a) proof.

**ADD:** I think I can construct analogous map for sheaves of vector spaces over a field using arbitrary injective resolutions, i.e. without using any resolutions with special properties.

Comment: Let me mention that this is essentially given by the lax symmetric monoidal structure on the derived pushforward $f_*\colon D(X)\to D(Y)$ for any map $f\colon X\to Y$, where in your case, $Y$ is a singleton. The point is that its left adjoint $f^*\colon D(Y)\to D(X)$ is symmetric monoidal: there is a canonical isomorphism $f^*\mathscr F\otimes^Lf^*\mathscr G\xrightarrow\sim f^*(\mathscr F\otimes^L\mathscr G)$.

Comment: @Z.M: A reference would be helpful.

Comment: @asv it’s an easy exercise to check that the right adjoint of a symmetric monoidal functor is lax symmetric monoidal

Answer (score 3):

I haven't looked at the article carefully, but perhaps R. Swan, *Cup products in sheaf cohomology, pure injectives, and a substitute for projective resolutions.*
J. Pure Appl. Algebra 1999 contains what you want.
The first few lines read:

> Since the beginning of the subject it has been known how to construct cup products in the cohomology of sheaves on a topological space. The construction uses special properties of the canonical flabby resolution. ... The object of the present paper is to give two new definitions for these products using only standard techniques of homological algebra: resolutions and derived functors.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is the cup product, see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01FP

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I edited my question. Chech cohomology is usually isomorphic to other definitions of cohomology, so have to ask my question more precisely.

Comment: Yes in general there is this https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/068G

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be relevant. However this is cup product for complexes of modules over a ring, not sheaves.

Comment: @asv if your original question was answered, you should accept the answer. If you then realise you wanted to ask something else but you didn't word it right, you should open a new question.

Comment: @FernandoMuro: Well, my original question was about cohomology, but I did not mean Chech cohomology. Hence I had to state it more precisely.

Comment: @asv you're right. However, sheaf cohomology is isomorphic to Czech cohomology in many many cases of interest.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a special case of the adjunction morphism.

Lemma: Let $i:Y \to Z$ be a closed embedding. Then for any sheaf $A$ on $Z$ there is a natural map from $H^*(Z,A)$ to $H^*(Y,i^*A)$.

Proof: We have $H^*(Y,i^*A)=H^*(Z,i_*i^*A)$ (here I am using the fact that $i$ is a closed embedding; for general $i$ you need to take derived direct image).
Since $i^*$ is left adjoint to $i_*$, we have the natural map $A\to i_*i^*A$ -- then just apply $H^*(Z,?)$ to this map.

Now take $Y=X, Z=X\times X$, $i$ -- the diagonal embedding, $A=\mathcal F\boxtimes \mathcal G$. (By the way if you work over $\mathbb Z$ as opposed to working over a field, then you need to be careful about what you mean by tensor product over $\mathbb Z$. Over a field it is obvious that the cohomology of $\mathcal F\boxtimes\mathcal G$ is literally the tensor product of cohomologies of $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$).